# Why would a string variable later be returned as [object HTMLInputElement]?

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamically-generated

I define 2 variables as empty strings:

```
var userName = "";
var initials = "";
```

The user then inputs their name and initials into an input element:

```
function setUserName() {
  var inputUserName = document.getElementById('userName').value.toString();
  var inputInitials = document.getElementById('initials').value.toString();

  console.log(inputInitials, inputUserName);

  userName=inputUserName;
  initials=inputInitials;

  console.log(userName,initials);

  $(".studentName").html(inputUserName + ' ');
  $('.initials').html('<strong>' + inputInitials.toUpperCase() + '</strong>');
};
```

The console logs state things properly, and if I add 'typeof' before them, they are strings.

I have a separate file that is use to generate select elements with options. a: being answer selection, c: being correct. These do come from within an object

```
var data =  [{
        s: "2",
        f: "3",
        q: "10",
        b: ["branchA"],
        a: ["TT", initials, "MN"],
        c: initials,
        t: "dropdown"
    },
 ...many more objects...
];


function appendAnswers() {
  loadedSituations.push(situationToLoad);
  for (var i = 0; i <= data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i].b.indexOf(selectedBranch) !== -1 && data[i].s === situationToLoad) {
      var checkBox = '<span class="checkmark"></span><span>' + data[i].l + '</span>';
      var select = '<option value="' + data[i].a[0] + '"> Select Answer </option><option value="' + data[i].a[1] + '">' + data[i].a[0] + '</option><option value="' + data[i].a[2] + '">' + data[i].a[1] + '</option><option>' + data[i].a[2] + '</option>';
      var currentQuestion = data[i].s + data[i].f + data[i].q;
      (data[i].t === 'dropdown' ? $('#s' + currentQuestion).append(select) : $('#s' + currentQuestion).append(checkBox));
    }
  }
}
```

but when the variables are loaded into the selects, they display as [object HTMLInputElement] and I am uncertain how this is occurring.

Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for you time!

Comment: What is the code that creates the object that displays `[object HTMLInputElement]`?

Comment: I will add it above. Apologies.

Comment: `initials`, without quotes, could be the `input` element with that ID from the DOM. Some browsers create global variables for elements with IDs. Without seeing the rest of the code, it's hard to say much else.

Comment: It's definitely what @HereticMonkey said -- the fact that there's an `<input>` element whose id is `initials` is clearly causing the unintended population of the `initials` variable. My guess is that your `{ a, c }` object is being populated with properties chronologically before you run `initials=inputInitials`, so `initials` has not yet has its input-element value overwritten.

Comment: I think you are definitely correct in that.I updated the code above. I am uncertain the best way to prevent such. The elements aren't actually appended until later, but I assume they are populated before hand.

Comment: Now that you've posted your full code -- even if you didn't have the `[object HTMLInputElement]` problem, you'd just have an unpopulate `initials` variable. `initials` isn't given a value until after `appendAnswers` runs, so don't refer to `initials` outside of `appendAnswers` (or if you do, make sure `appendAnswers` has at least run once before you do so). I'm guessing the solution here is to add those `a` and `c` properties inside of `appendAnswers`

Comment: I was hoping that the userName variable would be updated by the setUserName() function above. I think I have grown too comfy with Vue and 2 way binding, and now having to go back to jquery for this its thrown me off a bit. Suggestion on a best approach for this?

Comment: If you put all your code in an `IIFE`, the local variables `initials` and `userName` will shadow the global variables that are created from the IDs.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Creating those global variables is actually an HTML5 requirement, so all browsers should do it.

Comment: So did I update the global variable wrong, or what is a solid way to correct or address this issue? I do very much appreciate the assistance.

Comment: With your assistance and suggestions I've fixed my issue. I renamed data to localData and declared it locally within a separate function: ```pushLocalData() ``` that was called at the end of ```setUserName()``` that pushed the necessary content into the global 'data' variable. Doing so allowed me to get the desired outcome. If someone would like to write an answer to the tune of such, I'd gladly mark it correct. Thank you all again for your help!